# HTML5 Android Development

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am interesting in making an android application, while my primary hobbies is web development. Now the thing that is confusing me is that people make applications in HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript languages, are those apps running on web browsers on android mobile or running like an installed application on android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can design and develop your app in 3 ways

- Native: full Java code in Android case, or Objective-C or Swift now in iOS
- Web: HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript
- Hybrid: a mixture of the two

If you are a web developer you can design your app in HTML5 and then use a wrapper like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) which will simply wrap or package your app in a WebView (a Webview is like a simple browser inside a native app).

Then ***you will have your APK like any other app in Google Play, so yes it's a full application that can be installed, updated and deleted of course, in any Android device***

But there is a difference between the two, like the speed varies depending on the app type:
previously, web apps couldn't gain access to the accelerometer, camera, gyroscope etc, but now with the bunch of APIs available, you do have the ability to access them in very simple ways.

**A full definition of a webView**

> The WebView class is an extension of Android's View class that allows
>   you to display web pages as a part of your activity layout. It does
>   not include any features of a fully developed web browser, such as
>   navigation controls or an address bar. All that WebView does, by
>   default, is show a web page.

More info about WebView [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: Note that the use of "native" here can be misleading, as "native" can also mean using lower-level languages such as C or C++.  For instance, the Android NDK makes this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be opened in web browsers. Those mobile application that is written in HTML5 are really web applications that have Mobile user interface. You can create and experience these projects using Visual Studio 2012. Go to new project -> Web -> ASP.Net MVC 4 Web Application -> in "select a template" choose Mobile Application