# How to develop Android applications with the help of these languages?

Tags: android

I know **C** and **C++** pretty well, and I know **Java** too (***sort of***). Apart from these, I know **HTML** and **CSS**, and a ***bit of Javascript*** too. Anyone help me start with developing an android application? Is my coding knowledge enough or do I need to work more on it? What exactly is the platform (the softwares/applications i need to install on my PC) and also most importantly **recommend me some online tutorials** (on youtube or some other interactive tutorial site like CodeAvengers)
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822587/html5-android-development

Comment: question too much repetitive and can be find out there by searching web.the best sight for going on with android development is their official website https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: It is obvious you have never tried to Google this. If you can, please write native Android applications in Java. See @SUMITKUMARSINGHDIXIT comment.